# Keymaping for re-indent source code in Vim

Tags: vim, vimrc, gvim

I have key mapping in my *~/.vimrc* file that re-indents edited source code on the fly. It looks like as follows:

```
" press F4 to fix indentation in whole file; overwrites marker 'q' position
noremap <F4> mqggVG=`qzz
inoremap <F4> <Esc>mqggVG=`qzza
```

Short explanation:

```
mq      place marker 'q' at cursor position
ggVG    select all text
=       re-indnet text
`q      return cursor back to position stored in 'q' marker
zz      center the display over the cursor
a       return to insert mode if called from it
```

It basically works, but has two shortcomings.

The first one is that it overwrites the *q* marker. I used this marker to store cursor position. I choose *q* because it is very unlikely that I would use this letter as a marker. Despite this, is there any more clever approach to achieve this, without destroying *q* marker?

The second one occurs in the insert mode, when the cursor is on the beginning of a line. In such condition, <kbd>F4</kbd> re-indents as expected, but also moves cursor one position right. I tried to fix it by using `<C-o>` instead of `<Esc>`, but it looks like `<C-o>` is applicable only to editor *:commands*, not to move commands. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the last jump mark (`m'`) as a temporary mark. To avoid using a different command to re-enter insert mode (`i` vs. `a`), you can use the `gi` command, which re-enters insert mode at the position where it was last exited:

```
inoremap <F4> <Esc>m'ggVG=``zzgi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `i` instead of `a` to keep the cursor at old position:

```
inoremap <F4> <Esc>mqggVG=`qzzi
```

I think you can't do better with `q` marker, from [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks):

> To set a mark, type m followed by a letter. For example, ma sets mark
>   a at the current position (line and column). If you set mark a, any
>   mark in the current file that was previously identified as a is
>   removed. If you set mark A, any previous mark A (in any file) is
>   removed.

You can not use a marker without destroying it.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit shorter:

```
inoremap <F4> <Esc>m'gg=G''zzgi
```

We no need to use visual mode to make indent corrections. Instead use visual mode to select and then re-indent (VG=) we can use re-indent with direction (=G).

Comment: You should explain your answer a little, e.g. how it is more clever and how it does not destroy the q marker ...